# Online public Database for testing TNS connectivity Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, tnsnames, tns

Using crystal reports 2011 I am unable to connect to a remote oracle database.
Getting Error : **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Using 32 bit Oracle 11g driver on 64 bit Windows.

The DSN is set up correctly and testing the connection works.

The DSN also works with other tools such as TNSPING and even Eclipse.

Is there any online public Oracle databases that I could try testing my connection via Crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are trying to connect to a TNS entry called "XYZ".

ORA-12154 is not saying that your tnsnames configuration for XYZ is incorrect - it is saying that we could not even *find* an entry called XYZ.  Which either means

- we could not find the tnsnames.ora file,
- we were looking at the wrong tnsnames.ora file

If you can set environment variables as part of your Crystal Reports environment, the try set TNS_ADMIN to the location of your tnsnames.ora file

Comment: Thank you . But I have already set the TNS_ADMIN user env variable.